# Reading the app engine logs.db file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to read the logs.db file with an external script, but I don't know what format it's in (it's binary) to know what to read it with. It's a massive rabbit hole to try to figure out the log_service module, and I'm hoping I can shortcut that and just open it into readable text some other way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an sqlite file, can just read it with sqlite3 module.